# why is the \n not being stripped in string.split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am wondering why the second print statement below does not remove the `\n` in output but the first print statement does.

```
   str1 = "Line1-abcdef \nLine2-abc \nLine4-abcd \ndfsdf"
    print (str1.split( ))
    print (str1.split(' ', 2))
```

Comment: output is as below:
first print:
['Line1-abcdef', 'Line2-abc', 'Line4-abcd', 'dfsdf']

second print:
['Line1-abcdef', '\nLine2-abc', '\nLine4-abcd \ndfsdf']

Comment: If you leave out the argument, it splits on whitespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.split()` with no arguments will split on runs of *any consecutive whitespace characters*.

So it is automatically treating " \n" as a single, 2 character separator.

`.split(' ')` with an argument, will now *only* split on the space character specifically.

From: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

Aside bonuses: `.split()` with no arguments ensures:

- Pre-stripped tokens (no trailing or leading whitespace)
- No `''` (empty), or any whitespace tokens

Both of those are actual really nice time savers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains it.. \n is treated as 2 consecutive spaces ..